# Yii 1 GridView Alpha Pager Search

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

HI i Want to create Alpha Pager search , search is working fine but when i click search it disturb UI like load header and menu second time and site start showing menu again

[image]

Here is **admin.php view page**:

```
<?php
/* @var $this AreaController */
/* @var $model Area */
$this->breadcrumbs = array(
    'Areas' => array('index'),
    'Manage',
);
?>
<h1>Manage Areas</h1>
<div>
    <?php
    echo CHtml::ajaxLink('F', Yii::app()->createUrl('area/admin'), array('data' => array('q' => 'F'), 'update' => '#area-grid'), array());
    echo CHtml::ajaxLink('E', Yii::app()->createUrl('area/admin'), array('data' => array('q' => 'E'), 'update' => '#area-grid'), array());
    //echo CHtml::link('S', array('area/admin', 'q' => 'S'), array('target' => '_blank'));
    ?>
</div>
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'id' => 'area-grid',
    'itemsCssClass' => 'table-bordered items',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'class' => 'editable.EditableColumn',
            'name' => 'Area',
            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 110px'),
            'editable' => array(//esditable section
                'url' => $this->createUrl('area/updateEditable', array('model' => 'Area', 'field' => 'status')),
                'placement' => 'right',
            )
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'editable.EditableColumn',
            'name' => 'status',
            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 100px'),
            'editable' => array(
                'type' => 'select',
                //'url' => Area::getStatusList(),
                'url' => $this->createUrl('area/updateEditable', array('model' => 'Area', 'field' => 'status')),
                'source' => $this->createUrl('area/getStatuses'),
                'options' => array(//custom display 
                    'display' => 'js: function(value, sourceData) {

                              var selected = $.grep(sourceData, function(o){ return value == o.value; }),
                                  colors = {"Active": "green", "InActive": "red"};
                              $(this).text(selected[0].text).css("color", colors[value]);    
                          }'
                ),
                //onsave event handler 
                'onSave' => 'js: function(e, params) {
                          console && console.log("saved value: "+params.newValue);
                     }',
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'data-username' => '$data->status'
                )
            )
        ),
    ),
));
?>
```

**Controller admin action code**:

```
public function actionAdmin() {
    $model = new Area('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values

    if (isset($_GET['Area']))
        $model->attributes = $_GET['Area'];

    $this->render('admin', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

**Model search function code**:

```
public function search() {
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
        $criteria->condition = 'Area like "' . $_GET["q"] . '%"  ';
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
    }
    $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
    $criteria->compare('Area', $this->Area, true);
    $criteria->compare('status', $this->status, true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}
```